# requests возвращает код, но токен там пустой

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, requests

У меня есть такой код:

```
import requests

header = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"}
    
r = requests.get("https://santehnika1.ru/personal/", headers=header)
print("Done!")
print(r.text)
```

В `r.text` он мне возвращает код страницы, но токен там пустой. Однако, если самому зайти на сайт, то токен будет, то есть это выглядит вот так:

```
<input type="hidden" id="token_check" name="token_check" value="" />
```

а должно:

```
<input type="hidden" id="token_check" name="token_check" value="50022" />
```

вот сайт: https://santehnika1.ru
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не должно, потому что токена на самом деле нет в коде страницы, он заполняется скриптом.

Comment: @andreymal у меня внизу всего кода страницы есть что-то похожее на токен:                                        <script>
try{document.form_auth.USER_LOGIN.focus();}catch(e){}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#token_check').val('51809');
});
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вытаскивание токена через регулярное выражение:

```
import re
import requests

header = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"
}

r = requests.get("https://santehnika1.ru/personal/", headers=header)
print("Done!")
# print(r.text)

m = re.search(r"\$\('#token_check'\).val\('(.+?)'\);", r.text)
token_check = m.group(1)
print(token_check)
# 40869
```

Токен вытаскивается этой строкой `(.+?)`, а `\` нужны для экранирования, т.к. `$`, `(` и `)` являются мета-символами регулярного выражения

Answer (score 5):

```py
import requests


url = 'https://santehnika1.ru/personal/'
header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

a = r.text.find("token_check').val('")
b = r.text.find("');\n});\n</script>")

token_check = r.text[a+19:b]
```

в переменной `token_check` будет строка с номером токена:

```
>>> token_check
64915
```